# Making a platformer with LOVE2D- Vertical levels lack collision past a certain point

Tags: lua, 2d, love2d

For an online class, I am creating a platformer with LÖVE2D and lua. Levels are generated by tiles- with tiles being filled in vertically for normal levels, and horizontally for vertical levels- with those tiles having IDs corresponding to whether they're solid or not. However, in vertical levels, after a certain point, tiles that should be collidable become non-collidable. (as can be seen [here](https://streamable.com/gsqriz))

I have a feeling that it has something to do with the tile map and how it's created. Something I've tried is changing the width of the level, which is how I found out that the width I set for my vertical level determines where the collision is cut off. For example, if the level is 16 tiles wide, the collision ends 16 tiles down, and if the level is 10 tiles wide, the collision ends 10 tiles down.

I haven't figured out what causes this yet. Could anyone help me out with this? Here's my code for the tile map:

```
TileMap = Class{}

function TileMap:init(width, height, orientation)
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    self.tiles = {}
    self.orientation = orientation
end

--[[
    If our tiles were animated, this is potentially where we could iterate over all of them
    and update either per-tile or per-map animations for appropriately flagged tiles!
]]
function TileMap:update(dt)

end

--[[
    Returns the x, y of a tile given an x, y of coordinates in the world space.
]]
function TileMap:pointToTile(x, y)
    if self.orientation == 'horizontal' then
        if x < 0 or x > self.width * TILE_SIZE or y < 0 or y > self.height * TILE_SIZE then
            return nil
        end
    
        return self.tiles[math.floor(y / TILE_SIZE) + 1][math.floor(x / TILE_SIZE) + 1]
    elseif self.orientation == 'vertical' then
        if x < 0 or x > self.width * TILE_SIZE or y < 0 or y > self.height * TILE_SIZE then
            return nil
        end
        return self.tiles[math.floor(x / TILE_SIZE) + 1][math.floor(y / TILE_SIZE) + 1]
    end
end

function TileMap:render()
    for y = 1, self.height do
        for x = 1, self.width do
            self.tiles[y][x]:render()
        end
    end
end
```

And here is my level maker for vertical levels:

```
VertLevelMaker = Class{}

function VertLevelMaker.generate(height, width)
    local tiles = {}
    local entities = {}
    local objects = {}

    local tileID = TILE_ID_GROUND
    
    -- whether we should draw our tiles with toppers
    local topper = true
    local tileset = math.random(20)
    local topperset = math.random(20)
    
    for y = 1, width do
        table.insert(tiles, {})
    end
    
    local leftPlat = height % 8
    local rightPlat = height % 8 + 4
    -- place all the ground as you go down
    for y = 1, 10 do
        tileID = TILE_ID_EMPTY
        for x = 1, width do
            table.insert(tiles[x], 
                Tile(x, y, tileID, nil, tileset, topperset))
        end
    end
    
    tileID = TILE_ID_GROUND
    for y = 11, height - 1 do
        table.insert(tiles[1],
            Tile(1, y, tileID, y == 11 and topper or nil, tileset, topperset))
        if leftPlat >= 8 then
            leftPlat = leftPlat % 8
            for x = 2, 6 do
                table.insert(tiles[x],
                    Tile(x, y, tileID, y == y and topper or nil, tileset, topperset))
            end
            tileID = TILE_ID_EMPTY
            for x = 7, width - 1 do
                table.insert(tiles[x],
                    Tile(x, y, tileID, nil, tileset, topperset))
            end
        elseif rightPlat >= 8 then
            rightPlat = rightPlat % 8
            tileID = TILE_ID_EMPTY
            for x = 2, width - 6 do
                table.insert(tiles[x],
                    Tile(x, y, tileID, nil, tileset, topperset))
            end
            tileID = TILE_ID_GROUND
            for x = width - 5, width - 1 do
                table.insert(tiles[x],
                    Tile(x, y, tileID, y == y and topper or nil, tileset, topperset))
            end
        else
            tileID = TILE_ID_EMPTY
            for x = 2, width - 1 do
                table.insert(tiles[x],
                    Tile(x, y, tileID, nil, tileset, topperset))
            end
        end
        tileID = TILE_ID_GROUND
        table.insert(tiles[width],
            Tile(width, y, tileID, y == 11 and topper or nil, tileset, topperset))
        leftPlat = leftPlat + 1
        rightPlat = rightPlat + 1
    end
    for x = 1, width do
        table.insert(tiles[x], 
            Tile(x, height, tileID, topper, tileset, topperset))
    end
    
    local map = TileMap(height, width, 'vertical')
    map.tiles = tiles
    
    return Level(entities, objects, map, width, height)
end
```

(Sorry if it's not worded the best, this is the first question I've posted here)
(Also, before you ask, height and width are put into the tile map backwards on purpose, it doesn't work the other way)

Comment: The issue is not very clear, but I have a few estimations about what could be causing it, I don't think is directly related to the state of the block, the issue seems to be with the collision system and/or coordinates, so you can try debugging the collision system and see if the core of the issue is there

Comment: Hmm, alright, I can try looking there. One thing I can remember from looking with print statements is that the check for tiles being collidable stopped being called at the height where the collisions stopped being called.

Edit: After running that test, I found out that, while the tiles are being rendered, their value in the tile map is nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it! The issue wasn't in the state of the tiles, it was instead in how they were arranged. After changing the structure of the tiles table in the vertical level maker so the tiles were sorted horizontally, I just needed to adjust the pointToTile function in the tile map to match it.